# Format point value in hightcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, graphics, highcharts, percentage

I have a graph with 2 line series. Points in each series are percent but I get them from the database in this format : 0.24 for 24% , 0.02 for 2% ...
Is there any method for multiply the value by 100 directly in my graph options ? I try to use pointFormat and pointFormatter but my test isn't succesfull...

My graph configuration :

```
options.evolRes.chart = {
    renderTo: 'container_graph',
    backgroundColor: '#F1F1F1',
    width: $('#container_graph:parent').width(),
    height: 700
};

options.evolRes.title = {
    text: 'Title',
    x: -20
};

options.evolRes.yAxis = [
    {
        title: {
            text: 'Result'
        },
        labels: {
            format: '{value}%'
        },
        min: 0, 
        max: 100,
        tickInterval: 10            
    }
];  

options.evolRes.xAxis = {
    categories: ['T1','T2','T3','T4','T5','T6'],
    labels: {
        rotation: -45,
        y: 20
    }
};

options.evolRes.tooltip = {
    crosshairs: true,
    shared: true,
    valueDecimals: 2
};

options.evolRes.series = [
    {
        name: 'Result X',
        data: [0.2, 0.85, 0.63, 0.05, 0.26, 0.85],
        yAxis: 0,
        type: 'areaspline',
        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix : '%'
        }
    },{
        name: 'Result Y',
        data: [0.25, 0.35, 0.73, 0.05, 0.16, 0.25],
        yAxis: 0,
        type: 'areaspline',
        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix : '%'
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: You can load data then multiply all of values by 100 in preprocessing. Last step is use modified data in highcharts.

Comment: @PandiyanCool Adding some code

Comment: you need to update series value also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try out this

```
  tooltip: {
        formatter: function () {
            var s = '<b>' + this.x + '</b>';

            $.each(this.points, function () {
                s += '<br/>' + this.series.name + ': ' +
                    this.y *100;
            });

            return s;
        },
        shared: true
    }
```

[sample fiddle :)](http://jsfiddle.net/AYWsW/512/)